# Azure Developer and Standard plan tier

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to understand how Azure charges for web app services, specifically during development. From my understanding, I selected the Free F1 (Dev/Test) plan, which is supposed to be free. For the database, I opted for the Compute tier Serverless 1 Core. On the right side, there is a database utilization window, and at the bottom, I can see an estimated cost of $5.26 per month.

However, when I analyze the costs, I notice that there are charges almost every day, ranging from $2 to $5 per day. If it says per month why do I have to pay per day?

[image]
[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

$5.26 cost is the storage cost/GB/month however there is a cost of compute as well which is calculated based on the utilization (basically how many virtual cores seconds you are using).

The daily cost you see is the sum of storage cost and compute cost.